# Msaccess 2010 -base on a report on a recordsource

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have looked at a previous example of yours detailed below. However I have a problem:

Heres my code it runs off a button on a form called Reports:

```
Dim dbs As Database

    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim varitem As Variant

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("Qry_rpt_cr")
    qdf.Parameters(0) = Forms!frm_reports.rmselectfilter.Column(1, varitem)
    qdf.Parameters(4) = Forms!frm_reports.rmselectperiod.Column(0, 0)
    qdf.Parameters(3) = Forms!frm_reports.rmselectperiod.Column(0, 1)
    qdf.Parameters(2) = Forms!frm_reports.rmselectperiod.Column(0, 2)
    qdf.Parameters(1) = Forms!frm_reports.rmselectperiod.Column(0, 3)

    Set grst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from Qry_rpt_cr")

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_cr_test", acPreview

    grst.Close

    Set grst = Nothing
End Sub
```

The question is the query needs five parameters to be passed to it and then open the recordset using the defined parameters and then open the report. But the code does not open. Its says an error on this line  Set grst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from Qry_rpt_cr") asking for 5 parameters but I have passed them earlier in the code. Any suggestions would be welcomed. HAppy to make a donation for a correct answer. ED

Example from your archives
From Access Web you can use the "name" property of a recordset. You resulting code would look something like this:

In the report

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.RecordSource = gMyRecordSet.Name
End Sub
```

In the calling object (module, form, etc.)

```
Public gMyRecordSet As Recordset
'...
Public Sub callMyReport()
    '...
    Set gMyRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * " & _
                                               "from foo " & _
                                               "where bar='yaddah'")
    DoCmd.OpenReport "myReport", acViewPreview  
    '...
    gMyRecordSet.Close  
    Set gMyRecordSet = Nothing
    '...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Access for a while , but i think you are setting the params for a query, and then running a different query.  Access is asking for params to be provided for the query you are asking ("select * from ..."), not the (named) query that your query references, if that makes sense.

This should be easily fixed, just run `OpenRecordset` from the QueryDef:

```
Set grst = qdf.OpenRecordSet
```

and then Access will include the query's params correctly.

Edit: Thx Remou

Comment: Perhaps `Set grst = qdf.OpenRecordset`